# [UIImageView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, uiimageview, selector, settext

I'm sorry if it has already been asked, but here comes the problem:

I get this message when I scroll fast the tableView :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a8f8d0'

Here is my code :

```
   NewsVideoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AudioCellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[NewsVideoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AudioCellIdentifier];
   }


   cell.backgroundView = [ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"news_bg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 0)] ];  
   cell.selectedBackgroundView = [ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"news_bg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 0)] ];



   UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
   [cellLabel setText:[masjid objectForKey:@"name"]];

   UILabel *cellDate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
   [cellDate setText:[[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"]];       

   UIImageView *cellImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
   NSString *imagePath = [masjid objectForKey:@"thumb"];
   [cellImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imagePath]]];

   UITextView *cellText = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
   NSString *postText = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];

   [cellText setText:postText];

   ...
```

And the line which fire this exception is  :

```
   [cellText setText:postText];
```

I saw that it's due to an over-retaining or under-releasing, but I don't find a way to fix it.

any help plz ?

Comment: It looks like the tagged view #5 is an image view, not a text view. Could that be possible?

Comment: When you assign a view to label or textview try cell.contentView instead of cell

Comment: @dasblinkenlight no, the tagged view #5 is a text view and not a image view. This is why I don't understand why it tell me [UIImageView setText:]: unrecognized selector

Comment: @R.A I did replace cell by cell.contentView when I assign the view but it didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UITextView *cellText = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
```

in this line of code  your TAG for UITextView is "5", i think you may have given diffrent ID for this View . First .

i had similler problem ....  i  found that  my Tag Was diffrent for TextView and Image View .

> how to Change TAG for a View ?
>
> > First select the View(ie UITextView) and than go to Attribute  inspector Tab ..... Under the ' View ' you will find 'TAG' write there
> > 5.

Answer (score 0):

`setText` is a `UITextView` method not `UIImageView`. Now as it mentioned in the comment, the cellText is not a `UITextView` instance, it seems to be `UIImageView` instance, then you trying to call `setText` method from a `UIImageView` instance which cause the app to crash. Try testing it to make sure:

```
   UITextView *cellText = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
   if([cellText class] != [UITextView class]){
        cellText = [[UITextView alloc]init];
   }
   NSString *postText = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];

   [cellText setText:postText];
```

This way, if `cellText` is not `UITextView` instance, it will init one for you.